# How to Update Password Using TastyPie PATCH

Tags: django, tastypie

I understand the basics of TastyPie, but the custom ModelResource methods are very confusing to me.  I am trying to make a PATCH api call to update the password of a user and the data is not running through the `set_password()` method and therefore being updated with the raw value and not the HASH in the database.  Here is my ModelResource:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        authorization = Authorization() 
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
        filtering = {
             'username': ALL,
        }
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
```

I am assuming I need to use the `obj_update` method here, but am not sure how to format this to run the password through the `set_password` method before the actual object is updated in the user table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use hydrate method to handle this raw_password to hash translation for all cases (POST, PUT, PATCH). I personally define a virtual field `raw_password` so as not to cause namespace conflicts, since Tastypie allows you to POST/PUT/PATCH objects back that you receive from GET requests (beside being a good practice):

```
def hydrate(self, bundle):
    if bundle.data.has_key('raw_password'):
        u = User(username='dummy')
        u.set_password(bundle.data['raw_password'])
        bundle.data['password'] = u.password
    return bundle
```

Comment: @ digivampire Thanks for this.  I feel like I am headed in the right direction here.  A few follow up questions:  Could you please elaborate on 'defining a virtual field', where is that done and how is it configured?  Also, what is the point of 'username='dummy''?  Also, Is there a way to debug the hydrate method to look at what is in the bundle?

Comment: At this point bundle only contains raw serialized data from which Tastypie will create a full blown model object. By virtual field I meant an entry that is read from serialized input but is not an actual TastyPie or Django's ORM field. Simply used to compute the password hash and put in place as if the client indeed knew the hash and submitted it in the request with `password=hash_of(raw_password)`. I wasn't sure if you had to specify username when instantiating the User object. Turn's out you don't have to, so ignore that :).

Comment: You can use django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password function instead of create user instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case password was getting hashed as hydrate() is called 3 times when creating new object.

I wrote about user management using tastypie on my blog as well - http://www.psjinx.com/programming/2013/06/07/so-you-want-to-create-users-using-djangotastypie/